# ggplot2 bar graph exported to pdf is made up of segments instead of a solid shape

Tags: r, ggplot2, adobe-illustrator

My problem is that when I output a ggplot bar graph as a pdf and import it in illustrator, each bar is made up of many tiny segments rather than being a single solid shape. How can I convert the bars to solid shapes either in illustrator or when exporting in R?

R code:

```
library("ggplot2")
data(diamonds)
gplot <- ggplot(diamonds, aes(cut,carat)) + geom_bar(stat="identity")
ggsave("gplot.pdf",gplot)
```

Screenshot of pdf imported into Illustrator:
[image: Screenshot Illustrator]

Comment: maybe trying exporting as SVG?  Or use the `Cairo::cairoPDF` device to export?

Comment: @BenBolker Tried saving as SVG and it froze while importing into illustrator (I'm guessing all those individual shapes are still there). Using CairoPDF didn't make a difference either

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that `geom_bar` is using `position="stack"` to draw all the little bars right next to each other to stack up to the big bar. You can have it only draw one bar for each category by pre-aggregating your data:

```
library(dplyr)
diam = diamonds %>% group_by(cut) %>% summarize(carat = sum(carat))

g2 = ggplot(diam, aes(x = cut, y = carat)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity")
ggsave("gplot2.pdf", g2)
```

This also has the advantage of rendering much faster both to the PDF and if you print the plot to your graphic device.